# request http client call and variable scope

Tags: node.js, typescript, request, google-cloud-functions, httpclient

In the good cloud function environment, Inside the request1 call, I am able to get the output for bodydayOfTheWeek.

But outside the request1 call, I get the output as undefined.

I am not sure why. Even though the let variable bodydayOfTheWeek is declared outside the request1 call.

So not sure how scope variables are working in the request call

```
const request1 = require('request');  
const url = 'http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/pst/now';
let bodydayOfTheWeek: any;
request1(url, { json: true }, (err: any, res: any, body: any) => {
  if (err) { return console.log(err); }


  console.log('inside day of the week');
  bodydayOfTheWeek = body.dayOfTheWeek;
  console.log(bodydayOfTheWeek); <-- works
});

console.log('outside day of the week');
console.log(bodydayOfTheWeek);  <-- undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(err: any, res: any, body: any) => { }` is asynchronous. Hence, `bodydayOfTheWeek` will be undefined outside the function, unless you get `body.dayOfTheWeek` through a Callback/Promise. Read More, https://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/

```
const request = require('request');  
const url = 'http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/pst/now';

// Callback
function getDay(callback) {
    request(url, { json: true }, (err: any, res: any, body: any) => {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }

        callback(null, body.dayOfTheWeek);
    });
}

getDay((err, data) => {
    console.log(data);
});


// Promise
function getDay() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(url, { json: true }, (err: any, res: any, body: any) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }

            resolve(body.dayOfTheWeek);
        });
    });
}


getDa().then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help. How do I write this promise code inside a google cloud function for Http trigger. I could not find a simple example any where.

Comment: Depending on the node version, native Promise should be available.